# How to show render time / page load time in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using Laravel and want to display render time / page load time in my web application. Can you help me?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Laravel defines a `LARAVEL_START` constant which contains the microtime of when the framework started booting. You could use that to calculate the difference.

You can use the following

```
This page took {{ (microtime(true) - LARAVEL_START) }} seconds to render
```

Comment: You can also round the result, for example to 3 digits after the comma. Like this: `{{ round(microtime(true) - LARAVEL_START, 3) }}`

Answer (score 6):

I would recommend `barryvdh/laravel-debugbar` package which can give you plenty of informations about request including executed queries, various load times and many more.

Answer (score 0):

You can use for debugging one of those package: [barryvdh/laravel-debugbar](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar) or [sebklaus/profiler](https://github.com/sebklaus/profiler)